# How do I upload media files(documents,videos and images etc.) to AWS amazon s3 bucket and use cloudFront for stream videos only

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried reading content [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/on-demand-streaming-unified-uploading-to-s3.html) to understand it. but I need little help to understand it more. If any one worked on AWS before.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you already tried? This site is meant to help with specific problems, not teaching basics.

Comment: That is a very accurate guide, If you can tell specifically which part you don't understand, we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I find below two videos explains both (Uploading files to S3 and CloudFront )

https://youtu.be/0p6A464_hZY?list=PLrddsXJR3w3hkW8ewj4geERPGN48wEqfE

https://youtu.be/e0M2BmwIVW0?list=PLrddsXJR3w3hkW8ewj4geERPGN48wEqfE

Comment: Thank you Vijaynath this was helpful.